# adding css class to layout render block code in product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to add CSS class to hide this block in product detail page. I tried `css_class=>'my_css_class'` but it is not working. Tried to add in `product_view` XML as well but there also it didn't work. Can anyone help how to get this working?

```
echo $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render',
                        "product.price.final",
                        [
                            'data' => [
                                'price_render' => 'product.price.render.default',
                                'price_type_code' => 'final_price',
                                'zone' => 'item_view'
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
                    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: You want to hide a block, 1 which block, 2. why you don't remove it via xml, 3. At least via your css file ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ
1. I want to hide "product.price.final" block, which is rendering price in product detail page.
2. I tried adding the class in catalog_product_view.xml as below but It dint work
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">hello</argument>
3. I need to add css class name in price div tag first and this css class is defined in css file only.

Answer (score 0):

Its Solved!
Instead of 'css_class'=>'my_class' it should have been 'css_classes'=>'my_class'.

Hope this will help someone!